# Bootstrap search bar with multiple input fields inline

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a website in Bootstrap and I need to make [filter bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJxVV.png) for items on page. How can I build bar with one or more input fields (red ones) and one or more dropdowns (blue one). Width of bar should always be 100% of col.

Here is example from [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/ixrqKSZSpw). How can I put everything in one line, just like in picture above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several different ways you could solve this. One way is to use form-inline and define a specific smaller width for the inputs...

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 form-inline">
  Price from
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="min">
  to
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="max">
  <select type="text" class="form-control input-sm">
      <option selected="">EUR</option>
      <option value="1">USD</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

http://bootply.com/sDZybGTQeT

Comment: Ok but if I use 2 columns and switch to mobile view on col-xs size all elements will be displayed one below another. Can it be fixed somehow, can I display all elements in one line on col-xs size?
http://www.bootply.com/5XcfDZfXRd

Answer (score 0):

You should use columns wisely in bootstrap. Sum of all columns should be 12 as bootstrap is 12 column grid. Try below code. See it in full page view.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
  Price from
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="min">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
  to
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="max">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
  <select type="text" class="form-control">
      <option selected="">EUR</option>
      <option value="1">USD</option>
   </select>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```